# How to search a Visual Studio Solution for all the projects it contains?

Tags: visual-studio

How do I take a Visual Studio Solution (.sln) as input and get a list of all the projects it contains?

Comment: What do you want to do with that?
Easiest method is: open it and you see all projects.

Answer (score 2):

This array will give you full solution details with project created with in solution...

```
public List<string> getAllProjectNames(string path)
    {
        string[] arr =  System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
        List<string> projects = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i].StartsWith("Project"))
            {
                string [] temp = arr[i].Split(',');
                projects.Add(temp[1]);
            }
        }
        return projects;
    }
```

Call this method like...

```
List<string> Arr = getAllProjectNames(@"D:\Projects\PersonalRD\SearchingList\SearchingList.sln");
```

after that try to search all project names where the string item starts with project...

Answer (score 1):

It's just a text file.  Open it up in a text editor and see.  You're looking for all the Project directives.  Writing a simple parser to just extract the *.vcproj names shouldn't be difficult at all.